# Display large chart inside a card in a Dashboard

Tags: scrolling, charts, dashboard, cards

I'm going to design a Dashboard, I know how to show the information but my client said to me that a cohort chart is going to have a lot of information. I wonder if it's ok to add to the card that contains the chart an arrow to expand the chart on another page and there add a link to go back to the dashboard or what is the best way to do this (when we need to show more information for each card). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The visual below is far more expressive than trying to explain. I'd recommend **not to collapse** the card that contains the **`chart and the visually presented data`** at least to be able to display more informative interface.

[image]